# Determining total number of lines connected to a line segment in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, geoprocessing

I have a line shapefile showing the street network for a major city in Africa. For each line segment, I want to calculate the total number of roads/streets connected to it. For example, the road highlighted in red is a line segment with 4 roads connected to it. How do perform this for all line segments in QGIS?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get line intersections.[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-oZPfgP3yM) shows line intersactions tool. Number of intersection points on line is the number of roads connected to that road. You can use spatial join to count points on line [Count number of points per line in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225190/count-number-of-points-per-line-in-qgis) .

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, and for directing my attention to the other tutorials!

Comment: Sorry to disturb you but do you know any efficient approach to classify a line segment having a dead-end in QGIS?

Comment: May be there is a simpler solution but I'd try as:
1. Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Extract Nodes(get all nodes)
2. Spatial join extracted nodes with source data.
3. Nodes that are on single line are dead-end nodes.
4. Lİne segment that has same segment_id with result of 4 is a segment with dead end.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this approach, I will give this try.