# Classifying lines based on number of points located on them using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, point, linestring, knn

I have a lines layer (roads) and a points layer (accidents).
I'm projecting the points on the lines with st_closestpoint so that I'm sure the accidents are located on the closest road line.
I now want to associate the points to the lines based on their (overlapping) position. I do not want to use a buffer.
The problem is that after I projected the points on the lines I, weirdly, cannot associate the resulting points (now located on the lines) with the lines themselves. I tried with st_intersect and st_crosses but with no success, as if the points and lines aren't actually sharing any coordinate.

What am I doing wrong?

How else could I classify the lines based on the number of points located on them?

Comment: The "Join attributes by location" or "Join attributes by nearest" processing algorithms should work fine for you, you can link the $id of the line feature or any other unique field from the line onto the points. than you can count each occurence of the same "id" in your point layer to know how many points are on your line

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225190/count-number-of-points-per-line-in-qgis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contrary to intuition, deriving a *Point* from a *Line* does not guarantee that it will be included in the vector that defines said *Line* - this is mostly due to floating point arithmetic and its inaccuracies.

You want to use a classic *(K)NN* search, with additional localization and aggregation, instead:

```
SELECT
  rd.id,
  COUNT(cs.frac) AS ac_count,
  ARRAY_AGG(cs.frac ORDER BY frac) AS ac_locs
FROM
  <roads> AS rd
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      ST_LineLocatePoint(rd.geom, ac.geom) AS frac
    FROM
      <accidents> AS ac
    ORDER BY
      rd.geom <-> ac.geom
    LIMIT
      1
  ) AS cs
GROUP BY
  rd.id
;
```

where (added as examples)

- `ac_count` simply counts the `<accidents>.geom` that are closest to each `<road>.geom`
- `ac_locs` lists the *fraction of line-length* at which each of the found `<accidents>.geom` occurred; you could replicate geometries from those fractions by using `ST_LineInterpolatePoint(ln.geom, cs.frac)`

*An index on `<accidents>.geom` makes this type of query highly performant.*

---

You could run a simple

```
SELECT
  id,
  cnt,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ac_count DESC) AS rnk
FROM
  <above_query>
;
```

to categorize your roads based on accident count, with 1 being the 'most dangerous' road.

---

I recommend to [further read](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knn+postgis) on multiple topics concerning *(K)NN* queries, to understand **`LATERAL` queries, distances and index usage**.

**Related:**

- [Finding nearest neighbor for each point in the same table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287774/nearest-neighbor/287810#287810)
- [PostGIS: ST_ClosestPoint join error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352900/postgis-st-closestpoint-join-error/352905#352905)
- [Optimizing my script; taking too long; distance between many objects PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268025/optimizing-my-script-taking-too-long-distance-between-many-objects-postgis/268168#268168)
- [Speedup function to calculate distance from centroid of building to river segment in PostgreSQL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337896/speedup-function-to-calculate-distance-from-centroid-of-building-to-river-segmen/337939#337939)